# When will Stack Exchange page display bug be fixed?

Tags: bug, design, ui

For the last weeks the page looks terribly distorted on all my browsers (Chrome, Safari and Firefox on Mac OS X Yosemite). Looks like a CSS problem.

[image]

Comment: I agree. Just checked that page on my mac with FF 33.1.1 - same broken layout :(

Comment: Same here! I am using Chome on OSX Yosemite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed some time ago.

Comment: No it wasn't. I reported this problem a long time ago - nothing was fixed.

Comment: @chi wat exaclty wasn't fixed???

Comment: Add comment button for example, Answer Your Question. This problems were long time ago.

Comment: Oh, just read attentively. My problem is another - buttons. Sorry for the comments.